# chrome extension remove script tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension

i looked everywhere trying to find an answer to this question. 
i want my extension to either disable all javascript on the page BUT to allow the insertion of a cotent script that will work. (so chrome.contentSettings.javascript is not a valid option for now)
Alternatively i want a way to remove all script tags before any of them fire (which is kinda the same thing)

i tried inserting content scripts to runat:document_start but the dom is not fully there at the time. itried adding a conte t s ript on tabs.onUpdate when state is loading but that is too late and as well as content scripts at document_end (all of which who try to remove script tags)  but it is still too late. 
in an act of desperation i tried altering the behavior of the getters and setters of element.innerHTML to. remove the tags but that did not work as well

i am trying to avoid sending an xhr request to location.href and parse and re_set the content as that is too intensive.

any ideas?

Comment: [chrome.contentSettings](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contentSettings.html).javascript

Comment: that disables the content scrips as well which I want to keep running ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After seeing your comments I think this might suit your needs.  It works by getting the page's source, render it to a DOM, disable all the JS and then put it back into the page. Not exactly what you wanted but should suit your case well...

**mainfest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Reload and Kill JS - Using a content script",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "<all_urls>" , "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["injectedCode.js"],
      "run_at" : "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "minimum_chrome_version" : "20",
  "manifest_version" : 2
}
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.storage.local.set({"blockhttp://paez.kodingen.com/":true});
```

**injectedCode.js**

```js
reloadAndKillJS = function() {
    document.documentElement.innerHTML = 'Reloading Page...';
    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    xhr.open('GET', window.location.href, true);
    
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        document.documentElement.innerHTML = 'Error getting Page';
    }
    
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var page = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
        page.documentElement.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    
        var newPage = document.importNode(page.documentElement,true);
    
        var nodeList = newPage.querySelectorAll('script');
        for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; ++i) {
            var node = nodeList[i];
            if (node.src) {
                node.setAttribute('original-src', node.src);
                node.removeAttribute('src');
            }
            node.innerText = '';
        }
    
        document.replaceChild(newPage, document.documentElement);
        delete page;
    
        // Do your thing here
    }
    
    xhr.send();
}
    
   
chrome.storage.local.get("block"+window.location.href,function(items) 
{
    if (items["block"+window.location.href]){
        window.stop();
        reloadAndKillJS();  
    }
});
```

Comment: hey there. thanks for your answer. while this works... i wrote in my initial post that exactly this is what I am trying to avoid .. to quote myself :)
"1. The last method allows users to take a picture on the spot using the HTML5 getUserMedia API[15] and accessing the user's webcam(in the case of a laptop/desktop), camera (in the case of a mobile device) or any other video-audio input device available to the system"

Comment: hehe, odd quote ;)..so you did, sorry...and it doesnt work anyway as anything running on a setInterval is still running.  I had another idea of using a background page and webRequest.onHeadersRecieved to insert a Content-Security-Policy that might have worked, but I dont seem to be able to mod the headers?..and have no idea why.  Another way might be to put a variation of the above in a content script and stop the page loading and then get it, but how does the content script know when to override?  Or maybe a frame with a CSP...anywayz, Good Luck :P

Comment: I know it doesnt work the way you want, but updated it so it does block JS...used the new storage api as Im to lazy to do messaging, thats why the minimum chrome version 20

Comment: myeah i see there is no way i can avoid re-fetching the page, at least until the issue with content.javascript is fixed to have an option for content scripts. I set your answer as the good one as it does offer a very concrete solution, for anyone else who might find this post and have a similar issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the only way to truly prevent scripts is with contentSettings. So you need to put your code somewhere else, in another domain, since contentSettings rules can be applied for specific URL's.

Put you content script to run at document start.

**contentScript.js:**

```
window.stop();
document.all[0].innerHTML = "\
<html>\
    <body>\
        <iframe src=\"chrome-extension://ID/inject.html?url="+encodeURIComponent(location.href)+"\"></iframe>\
    </body>\
</html>";
```

**inject.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var frame = document.querySelector('iframe');
    frame.src = location.search.replace('?url=', '');
    frame.onload = function() {
        //Your stuff here
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe></iframe>
</body>
<html>
```

Now your code is in a parent frame and in another domain, but it may cause some CORS issues which you can try found some workarounds later.
Give a try, then tell me if there's something to fix.

Comment: your solution sounds interesting but it does not work for me as i specifically need to access events in that page. I.e. when I click any page when my app is activated... do stuff but while app activated disable all js on visited pages

Comment: @tak3r, could you please add more details?

Comment: so i am doing an extension that provides users the ability to click on a webpage on different item, select a range of webpages and apply the patter to automatically scrape them

With that in mind, I need for the initial structure of the HTML to not be altered by JS => provide users with only the non-js functionality. In the same time i want to add event listeners for mouse clicks so I can catch them and get the path of the elements (chain of parents). If the js is altered by run-time javascript, the path the users clicks on will be invalid to scripts that only see the initial HTML

Comment: so I am inserting a content script in the webpages to bind the events and provide visual on-content feedback, but i need for a way to prevent all *native* script tags from running on the actual page